# how to keep special keys in filed of mongoDB documents and remove extra keys in there?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

suppose that I have mongoDB collection that has documents like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb2dd4d378a8e2484e7bb69"),
    "name":"ali",
    "creator" : {
        "name":"user1",
        "code":2,
        "type" : "desk",
        "type_id" : "desk::bb36640a-e384-45ec-aafa-ce71b724c389"
    },
     "creatorPosition" : {
        "name":"user2",
        "role":"admin",
        "type" : "position",
        "type_id" : "position::9f711bb3-3aad-4936-b75a-4ddd024b4bb1"
    },
     "creatorDetails" : {
        "name":"user1",
        "type" : "deskUserAssignment",
        "type_id" : "deskUserAssignment::dd46fa14-0fd3-43d7-8312-471bc253ee80"
    }
}
```

I want to keep two key values (`"type", "type_id"`) from each fields and remove extra keys (such as `"name", "code", "role"`)

Can I handle this in one mongo query?

In addition, I want to write this code in java

Comment: It's not a great schema. Something like `"data": [{ "info": "creator", "name":"user1", "code":2, "type" : "desk","type_id" : "desk::bb..." },{ "info": "creatorPosition", "name":"user2"," type" : "position", "type_id" : "position::9f..." }, { ... }]` is **infinitely** more useful to query and basically makes your problem a matter of simple projection for the "two" properties you want ( "three" with the "info" field of course ). Keeping that schema as it is does not have a well performing answer. You can do it, but with a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do is using Projection that [MongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) offers

For example including fields using  `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query` and `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate` for retrieving the results:

`Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("creator.type").include("creator.type_id");
query.fields().include("creatorPosition.type").include("creatorPosition.type_id");
query.fields().include("creatorDetails.type").include("creatorDetails.type_id");
List<Document> documents = mongoTemplate.find(query, Document.class, "your_collection");`

For more information see this Article: https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-select-fields-to-return/

Comment: unfortunately i don't know how many fields exist in each documents

Comment: Still you can extend it and use it for other fields too, for the example u showed above it should work 100%